# How can I filter email addresses that belong in a particular domain using Perl?

Tags: perl, email-address

How can I scan through a file which contains email addresses that are separated by a new line character and get rid of those that belong to a certain domain, e.g. `hacker@bad.com`. I want to get rid of all email addresses that are `@bad.com`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `grep` instead of Perl

```
grep -v '@bad\.com' inputfile > outputfile
```

On Windows

```
findstr /v "@bad\.com" inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: what about "me@bad.com.*"? Are also to be filtered out?

Answer (score 2):

[`Email::Address`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Address/) is a nice module for dealing with email addresses.

Here is an example which may whet you appetite:

```
use Email::Address;

my $data = 'this person email is hacker@bad.com
blah blah hacker@good.com blah blah
another@bad.com
';

my @emails      = Email::Address->parse( $data );
my @good_emails = grep { $_->host ne 'bad.com' } @emails;

say "@emails";       # => hacker@bad.com hacker@good.com another@bad.com
say "@good_emails";  # => hacker@good.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$badDomain = "bad.com";
while(<>)
{
        s{\s+$}{};
        print "$_\n" if(!/\@$badDomain$/);
}
```

Comment: Since we never `chomp()`-ed the line, it will already have a newline at the end by default. You don't need to print it with another one (unless of course you want blank lines between your output lines).

Comment: @Chris: If you look closely at line 4, I'm removing all trailing whitespaces. That will remove the trailing \n as well. So a \n in the print is needed.

Comment: Ah. In that case, why not `s/\s+$/\n/;` so the newline is kept, then just `print if /regex/` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following would allow you to have a script that you can enhance in time... Instead of simply filtering out @bad.com (which you can do with a simple grep), you can write your script so you can easily sophisticate which domains are unwanted.

```
my $bad_addresses = {'bad.com'=>1};

while (my $s = <>) {
    print $s unless (is_bad_address($s));
}

sub is_bad_address {
    my ($addr) = @_;
    if ($addr=~/^([^@]+)\@([^@\n\r]+)$/o) {
        my $domain = lc($2);
        return 0 unless (defined $bad_addresses->{$domain});
        return $bad_addresses->{$domain};
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too different of what others have done.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @re = map { qr/@(.*\.)*\Q$_\E$/ } qw(bad.com mean.com);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (grep { $line =~ /$_/ } @re) {
        print "Rejected: $line\n";
    } else {
        print "Allowed: $line\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
good@good.com
bad@bad.com
notbad@bad.comm.com
alsobad@bad.com
othergood@good.com
not@mean.com
good@reallymean.com
bad@really.mean.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if !/@bad\.com/' file
```

awk

```
awk '!/@bad\.com/' file
```

Comment: That's not the right pattern. It also excludes notbad.com, etc.

Answer (score -3):

this code should filter all the @bad.com address from the input files.

```
 my @array = <>;

 foreach(@array) {
   if(!/\@bad.com$/) {
     print $_;
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's awful. Why would you slurp in `<>` when you could just iterate over it for the same effect, with almost no memory impact?